# Desktop file icon hijacks every newly opened terminal window

Tags: 14.04, command-line, .desktop

I have a desktop file that runs the following script:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=MYAPP
Icon=/usr/local/myAppDir/AppIcon.png
Exec=/usr/local/myAppDir/myApp
```

It does work, that is not the problem. It opens a new terminal since myApp requires a terminal to run in the background. But every time I open a new terminal, it gets hijacked by the myApp icon. What I mean by that is that in the side bar, it looks like I have 3 myApp windows opened after I click the terminal icon 3 times. The terminal icon, when clicked on keeps opening new terminals instead of opening the most recent one. Is this changeable?

Comment: I tried the solution given, but I think OP, just like me, prefers to have a dedicated icon for the background processes. Is this not doable without hijacking either the terminal icon or the .desktop icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application windows of one and the same application can in principle only be grouped in one application icon, so all gnome-terminal windows are grouped in one icon. Normally that improves the coherence of the launcher.

A side effect is that if you have your application run in the terminal from a `.desktop file`, and the terminal window appears under the icon of your application, all terminal windows you open while your application is running are grouped under that same icon of your application, until you close your application.

Unless...

You add a non-sense `StartupWMClass=` line to your application's `.desktop file`:

```
StartupWMClass=Monkey
```

Then your application will appear under the terminal's icon. New terminal windows will as well.

#### Note

The effect mentioned above occurs only when the command you run in your application's  `Exec=` line is the *main* command of your `.desktop` file. It does not happen from possible shortcuts you add to an existing launcher.

Since it seems a terminal-only script, another, and probably cleaner solution would therefore be to add the scipt as a shortcut to your existing `gnome-terminal` launcher (or any other icon that seems appropriate). In that case you would have to replace the line (in a local copy of the gnome-terminal.desktop file):

```
Actions=New
```

by:

```
Actions=New;Myapp;
```

and add at the bottom of the file:

```
[Desktop Action MyApp]
Name=MyApp
Exec=gnome-terminal -x bash -c "/usr/local/myAppDir/myApp"
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```